# Serendipitous results observed whilst layering a div on-top of another, without using z-index

Tags: css, css-float, position, z-index

I have two divs, (100px by 100px) stacked one on-top of the other, where the bottom div has a black border on top: see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fgHAa/)

```
<div id="top"></div>
<div id="bottom"></div>​

div { 
  width: 100px; 
  height: 100px; 
}

#top { 
  background: tomato; 
}

#bottom { 
  border-top: 1px solid black; background: gold; 
}
```

I want to use the top div to obscure the border on the bottom one. (I can't remove the border in this instance).

Normally, I would do this by setting `position: relative` and `z-index` on both divs, (ensuring that **div#one** has a higher `z-index` than **div#two**), and then adding `margin-bottom: -1px` to **div#one**, see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fgHAa/1/) - the css thus becomes:

```
div { 
  width: 100px; 
  height: 100px; 
  position: relative; 
}

#top { 
  z-index: 9999; 
  margin-bottom: -1px; 
  background: tomato; 
}    

#bottom { 
  z-index: 1; 
  border-top: 1px solid black; 
  background: gold; 
}
```

But I was messing around earlier, and noticed that if I float the top div (whilst keeping the negative bottom margin), and clear the bottom one (so that they stay stacked vertically), then I don't need to use `position: relative` or z-index to hide the border, just so long as I add the negative bottom margin to the top div (as opposed to a negative top margin on the bottom one) - see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fgHAa/2/)

```
div { 
  width: 100px; 
  height: 100px; 
}

#top { 
  float: left; 
  margin-bottom: -1px; 
  background: tomato; 
}    

#bottom { 
  clear: both; 
  border-top: 1px solid black; 
  background: gold; 
}
```

This works fine, and I prefer it because there is less code to write. So what's happening here? Is this a valid, cross-browser way of layering one thing on-top of the other, or is it best to stick to the first method, where I'm using z-index, like I always have done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a cross browser issue. Better to stick to the first method I reckon.